# Writing a matrix in terms of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've looked for examples but found none similar to this;

I have $\mathfrak{sl}(2,K)$ with the given basis $S$ as follows:

$S=\{e,h,f\}$ where

$e = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$
$h = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}$
$f = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$

I am told when the matrix e is written in terms of this basis it is:
$E = \pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &  0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2}$

Why is this the case? thank you

Comment: To display $a = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$, just type `$a = \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$`.  To say that $L$ is a member of the special linear group, i.e. $L \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \Bbb K)$, simply type `$L \in \operatorname{SL}(2, \Bbb K)$`.  For more information, see our [tutorial on MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Though if you're talking traceless, you *might* mean the special unitary group $\operatorname{SU}(2,\Bbb K)$ (or its Lie algebra $\operatorname{su}(2,\Bbb K)$): `$\operatorname{SU}(2,\Bbb K)$`.  Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding your notation "sl(2, k)", but it would be cleared up if you took the time to edit in MathJax formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, tidied it up a bit now

Comment: Clearly, the matrix $e$ which is already a member of the basis would be written as $1\cdot e+0\cdot h+0\cdot f$, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Bye_World $SU$ would certainly contain the identity matrix, which does *not* have trace zero. Instead, I gues that $\mathfrak{sl} (2,\mathbb K)$ was quite correct - after all trace zero becomes determinant one unter exponentiation.

Comment: What is the source of this?  Did it come from your lecture, or textbook, or some website?

Comment: They're from a lecture.

Comment: What I have denoted as E above he has denoted as M subscript S(h). I interpreted this as meaning the matrix of h with respect to basis S. I may have been wrong

Answer (score 0):

All that I can interprete into your $E$ is that it ought to be a linear map $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb K)\to\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb K)$. It looks like the Lie bracket with $h$ perhaps: $x\mapsto[h,x]$.